# Google "Define:" command API

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, api

I had a quick question about Google. Whenever you use the "define" command it gives you a definition of the word. For example, if I type `define:living` into Google, it will pull up a card-like result showing the definition of the word. Usually from Wikipedia or something. I was wondering how I would have my website give back a definition when they use the define command on a word. Is it some kind or API or something else? Thanks!

Comment: This comes from the knowledge graph which is comprised of data from very high authority sites. Some of this is algorithmic, however, the definition of terms is very likely not. In short, I am fairly sure you cannot influence definitions in Google. Or at least not without an insane amount of authority.

Comment: Maybe you could add that as an answer @closetnoc so that this question can be marked as answered.